# Enum class copy

Tags: java

I'm having two Enum Class have same type of elements in it. How can I copy value from class A to class B ?

```
public enum A{
    EAST,
    WEST,
    NORTH,
    SOUTH;
}
public enum B{
    EAST,
    WEST,
    NORTH,
    SOUTH;
}
```

Comment: NO, you cant. Its not verbal language to do such things

Comment: Why, and why do you need to?

Comment: @Dave Newton It could be that classes needs to have some mapping.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/186652). Consider describing why you think you need to do such thing so we could find some possible alternative solution because what you are describing seems almost impossible.

Comment: Creating a wrapper, I cant touch the existing class A so, the class B can have more elements tomorrow.

Comment: @Alex I understand, but without knowing the problem trying to be solved, it's harder to provide meaningful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
A a = A.EAST;
B b = B.valueOf(a.name());
```

or as in the comment below

```
B b = B.valueOf(A.EAST.name());
```

depending on how you use enum in your code.

Comment: :~B b = B.valueOf(A.EAST.name());B b = B.valueOf(A.WEST.name());B b = B.valueOf(A.NORTH.name());B b = B.valueOf(A.SOUTH.name());~ Do I need to copy like this each values ?

Answer (score 0):

How about having one enum that implements two interfaces?

```
enum A implements Side, Direction {
   ...
}
```

Or one enum composed of two things?

```
enum A  {
   public Side asSide(){return side;}
   public Direction asDirection(){return direction;}
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ant task that copy `A.java` to `B.java`, and replace `enum A` by `enum B`.

You can also do it using bash:

```
sed -r -e 's@enum\s+A\b@enum B@g' A.java >  B.java
```

Now, since the two `enum` are mean to be the same, you should probably wrap them using two side class:

- you would not do this ugly thing.
- if you have `WrapperA` and `WrapperB` using `EnumC`, you can later have `WrapperA` hold `EnumA` and `WrapperB` hold `EnumB`.

Doing this way would be more maintainable, than having some obscure task do a dirty job: you would profit from compilation, and versioning too.